# How do I bind an array to ngModel?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to bind a variable list of input elements to an array. Lets say I have an array

```
$scope.set = [{id: 1, value: 'foo'}, {id: 2, value: 'bar'}]
```

I would like to loop over that array and create an input element for each item.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in set">
  <input id="{{item_$index}}" ng-model="myModel.items[]"/>
</div>
```

I realize the above ng-model attribute is incorrect. What is the proper way to accomplish this requirement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `item.value` in `ng-model` so that it can bind its value and that element `item` value will change when there is update.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in set">
  <input id="{{item.id}}" ng-model="item.value"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this perhaps?

```
ng-model="item.value"
```

Comment: you beated me by 7 sec.that awesome :)

Comment: Won't this bind all of the input elements to the same property on the model?

Comment: Nope, because `item` is a foreach variable.

Comment: did you looked at mine answer :p

Answer (score 1):

You code looks good, but `item_$index` is undefined. If you want the index in the ng-repeat loop, use `{{$index}}`. See the [ngRepeat docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) for what 'magic' bindings you can use. Or just use `item.id`.

The ng-model can be anything of `item`.
Do `ng-model="item"` or `ng-model="item.value"` for example. Since `input` has `type="text"` by default, `item.value` seems the most logical choice.